# LED Lighting Automation + Bluetooth

Tags: automation, home-electronics, led

I am looking for a LED light and a wall switch that are both connected to each other via Bluetooth.

I would like the switch to be able to toggle the light on/off, but I don't want the switch physically wired to the light. The light would be wired directly to the power and be always on.

Basically, I want a "pull chain" light bulb, that the "pull chain" is a Bluetooth signal that can be sent from a Bluetooth switch or an app.

Plus if the products are HomeKit or Nest Weave products.

Comment: Do you have a budget?

Comment: Eh, not really. I mean I'm not looking to spend $100 per light, but I know this might not be cheap. lol

Comment: Might be easier & cheaper to wire up a PLC and Relays lol

Comment: [Let Me Google That For You](https://www.google.com/search?q=bluetooth%20light%20switch&hl=en-GB&complete=0&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: @EdwardNunn, that doesn't help. Those are not what I am looking for. Those are Bluetooth switches that are hard-wired to light fixtures. Not what I asked. tyvm.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was a very generic Google search after all, I though it might bring up something of interest. Have you actually tried using a little Google Fu to find what you were looking for?

Comment: Yea I searched for about an hour before giving up and asking for help. Nothing was really what I was looking for. Everything was connected by hard wire at some point. I only want the electricity to be the hardwire. Everything else is wireless., if possible :)

Comment: Ohhhh, I now visualise the product you are looking for. I will search and see what I can find. I thought you meant a light switch that connects to your phone but what you want is a light switch that sends a Bluetooth signal to the bulb/fixture itself yes?

Comment: Exactly. I know there is something similar in motion detector bulbs i found from phillips. But instead of the motion detector controlling the bulb, id like a bluetooth signal (or wifi or rf or whatever) to do it from the switch. Bonus would be either mobile connection to the switch or to the bulb as well, but not required :)

Comment: I suppose I can wire up a Raspberry Pi to the bluetooth switches via relays, and then turn on the light via relays. But thats a whole hell of a lot more wiring than wireless :)

Comment: A lot of lighting uses the mains, but has a 0-10v dimmer line.  You might be able to do that without relays.